# How to change the opacity of an image.

Tags: android

I have an background image set to an `ImageView`, Now i want to change the opacity of an image without, for that i write this code to change the opacity of ImageView, but when i do so it remove the background image from the image view, So my question is how can i change the opacity of ImageView without removing background image form it.

**Code i used is:**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.theme1_page_header); // Set background image

int opacity = 100; // from 0 to 255
imageView.setBackgroundColor(opacity * 0x1000000); // change opacity of image
```

Answer (score 35):

the most important part of alpha is that the value has to be decimal

0 = transparent and 1 = visible

so 0.5 is half way visible

in the XML you can do

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:alpha="0.4" // <-----------------  this is the fun part
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:background="@drawable/imagename"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
imageView.setAlpha(yourValue); //  some value 0-255 where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha%28int%29)

Comment: thanks for the answer but value is not 0-255, it should be in the range between 0-1 as float

Answer (score 5):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Drawable dPage_header= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.theme1_page_header);

// setting the opacity (alpha)
dPage_header.setAlpha(10);

// setting the images on the ImageViews
imageView.setImageDrawable(dPage_header);
```

Comment: But it is not about your first question. You can do this by checking your work percentage. you can create an method which return complatedWorkPercentage() and gives this valu to dPage_header.setAlpha(complatedWorkPercentage());

Comment: i dont know what is the work  ? Could you send me  detail email to talhakosen@gmail.com

Comment: Hi talhakosen...i have send a reply to ur mail..can u please check it out

Answer (score 2):

> For Api >=16 . Use setImageAlpha as your practice because setAlpha will be deprecated in coming future. `

`ImageView.setAlpha(int)` has been `renamed` to `ImageView.setImageAlpha(int)` to avoid confusion. See [**Detail Explanation here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551723/3496570)

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin we can change alpha in code like this:

```
myImageView.alpha = 0.5f
```

Change alpha value to whatever you want between 0.0f to 1f

Answer (score 1):

Use this option in layout xml for opacity as well as to turn the Android Material icons from Black to Grey.
android:alpha=0.5

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

Use `imageView.setAlpha(100)`.

If you're using Android 2.3 you have to do a horrible hack with a zero-length animation using nineolddroids.

## Option 2

Subclass `ImageView` and override its `onDraw()` method to draw the image transparently.

## Option 3

Actually modify the image pixels using `get/setPixel()`. This'll be very slow though; there's probably a faster way to do this (e.g. using renderscript).

Answer (score 0):

If your sdk version is on or above 31, then you can simply instantiate the image variable and then you can blur the image. This is the simplest way without any dependencies (e.g., Kotlin).

This is the code:

```
lateinit var backgroundImage : ImageView
backgroundImage = binding.imgWhole
backgroundImage.setRenderEffect(RenderEffect.createBlurEffect(10F, 10F,Shader.TileMode.MIRROR))
```