# Android ImageView - setAlpha(float) vs setImageAlpha(int)

Tags: android, performance, imageview, alpha

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551723/2810825) answer as a reference, I understand that a `View's` `setAlpha(float)` basically draws the view normally on a buffer, then uses a 2nd pass to draw the view with the alpha value on the scene, and because of this, setting a `View's` alpha usually involves harming the performance of the app.

However, `ImageViews` have another method called `setImageAlpha(int)` which, from what I've gathered, applies the alpha value on the `ImageView's` colour filter - removing the need for a 2nd pass all together and is therefore much more efficient.

My question is - since using `setImageAlpha` on an `ImageView` is much more efficient, is there any reason to ever use `setAlpha(float)` on an `ImageView`? Or should this be avoided in general in favour for `setImageAlpha(int)?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the literal meaning of the methods, I guess `setImageAlpha` sets the image's alpha *only*. If the image view has a background, the background would not be translucent. But `setAlpha` sets the *whole* view's alpha value.